# Selectively Redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS requests in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http, https

What's the simplest and most effective way to selectively redirect HTTP requests to your ASP.NET page to its HTTPS equivalent?

For example, if my page site URL is http://www.somesite.com, I want to redirect some (or all) page requests to https://www.somesite.com.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code to do that.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx

I like to say, that the only minus is that is not use **"Regular expression pattern matching"**, but it was very easy to add it on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of IIS you are using and whether you have access to it and whether you want to write custom code or configure a product feature.

IIS5, IIS6:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

IIS7, IIS7.5:

URL Rewrite:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Here's an example of a rule to redirect http://.../checkout.aspx to https:

```
<rule name="CheckoutToSSL" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^checkout.aspx*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```

ASP.NET Routing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Difference between IIS7,7.5 rewrite and ASP.NET routing

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/